# Application insight NLog target

Tags: c#, nlog, azure-application-insights

I have console application from which I want to send custom events to my Application Insight. I want to use Application Insight NLog target (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.NLogTarget/) but it's not working. I tried to set it via .config file and tried to set it manually:

```
    var config = new LoggingConfiguration();
    ConfigurationItemFactory.Default.Targets.RegisterDefinition("ai", typeof(ApplicationInsightsTarget));
    ApplicationInsightsTarget aiTarget = new ApplicationInsightsTarget();
    aiTarget.InstrumentationKey = "my_key";
    aiTarget.Name = "aiTarget";
    LoggingRule rule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Info, aiTarget);
    config.AddTarget("aiTarget", aiTarget);
    config.LoggingRules.Add(rule);
    LogManager.Configuration = config;
```

but still nothing, I can't see my exceptions or events in application insights. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you followed documentation [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet-logging) (which is pretty close to what you implemented):

```
var config = new LoggingConfiguration();

ApplicationInsightsTarget target = new ApplicationInsightsTarget();
// You need this only if you did not define InstrumentationKey in ApplicationInsights.config or want to use different instrumentation key
target.InstrumentationKey = "Your_Resource_Key";

LoggingRule rule = new LoggingRule("*", LogLevel.Trace, target);
config.LoggingRules.Add(rule);

LogManager.Configuration = config;

Logger logger = LogManager.GetLogger("Example");

logger.Trace("trace log message");
```

Then, I'd double check with Fiddler if anything gets sent out of the box to dc.services.visualstudio.com and what's the response code. That might give a clue about the issue if the problem is indeed with the transport but not collection.

If the issue is in collection, you can troubleshoot it locally with [PerfView and other Diagnostics tools.](http://sergeysharp.com/blog/2015/04/16/diagnostic-of-applicationinsights-sdk/)

PerfView command to collect AI traces would look like:

```
PerfView.exe /onlyProviders=*Microsoft-ApplicationInsights-Extensibility-Web,*Microsoft-ApplicationInsights-Web,*Microsoft-ApplicationInsights-Core,*Microsoft-ApplicationInsights-Extensibility-DependencyCollector,*Microsoft-ApplicationInsights-Extensibility-Rtia-SharedCore,*Microsoft-ApplicationInsights-Extensibility-WindowsServer,*Microsoft-ApplicationInsights-WindowsServer-TelemetryChannel collect
```

Answer (score 0):

For my console application, I have read "INSTRUMENTATIONKEY" from App.config at run time.

So first I added "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY" as a key at App.config.

```
<appSettings>
    ....
    <add key="APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY" value="your key" />
    ....
</appSettings>
```

Then read and set this key at Main function by adding below lines.

```
var key = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY"];   
Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration.Active.InstrumentationKey = key;
```

Then at the end of you Main function or in your closing function add a thread.sleep for giving some time to send data to Application Insights.

```
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(70000);
```